# Get image by REST call and display on android

Tags: android, rest

Here is the link where I place a REST GET call.
http://adtouch.cloudfoundry.com/rest/ad/barcode/529a927973654526a309a77986062566/image
On opening it in browser, it redirects to other link and I get an image displayed.
I want to display this image on android. I am unable to determine what is the content I get by this call and how to convert it to an image to be displayed on android device.

This is the rest call I make:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
String temp = "http://adtouch.cloudfoundry.com/rest/ad/barcode/529a927973654526a309a77986062566/image";
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(temp);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String result =  httpclient.execute(request, handler);
System.out.println(result);
```

The result of this is numerous sequence of characters like:

```
(^( ?( ;QE??QE??ÊMÔâ1MT ??²¤i­@íù¨ùhÙQ¶ê??m7Í¡?mFÏ@3|µu]¿Þ§+Uò?\°Ñ³Qçý?o?MiUWt?*¯÷?ª9Jæ·û´Ý¿59_åùi¬Õq$jE¨)ÿ??Á@D°?©ËÒªÆß7Þ«?õ   q?/ÉR+Tr%F?¨(·LÙQ­9]¨Ê´í?½;}??5???¨ßE??º?ôúc÷ ?·éGÍíFæZ??M­K·ûÔè÷?Þ©<¥Û@Æ?ýÚ±üÕEJ7l O?Z³YêÄÒï¨ÕhK{}ë¹¾íZ?>U¨c}?RG@QGðüÍM2®>\·û´??í?l¨ÿ??xßÂ«NUþón }Ênÿ??î­9UR???nÖ?Å·ýÚo?¿Ä»¿Þ©(
```

I know how to set an image to the ImageView but the question is how to get an image from this call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the Javadoc for [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html). You must decode the stream in the HTTP response's entity:

```
InputStream in = client.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decode(in);
in.close();
```

Note that network operations should not happen in the main thread. From your code it's not clear if you use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or not, however you should. Update the image in the `onPostExecute()` hook.

Comment: You can also simplify this immensely by using the excellent UrlImageViewHelper library, which will download, cache and display an image in an ImageView automatically.

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Comment: Thanks @Raffaele . It works. Just a small change. I am using Google API level 16 and so it should be Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);